# Restrict Heroku Postgres connects from inside our AWS security group

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Does anyone know if it is possible to remove the external connectivity of a Heroku Postgres database?

We'd like to limit connects to the PG database from only our application nodes via our security groups.

Using RDS this is possible, and we're looking at migrating to Heroku Postgres, but this would be a show stopper from a PCI point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to limit requests to specific security groups.

For PCI compliance we strongly encourage you to use a PCI compliant gateway such as https://www.braintreepayments.com or https://stripe.com and never store any CC information locally at all. This is in fact how Heroku itself charges our users.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the answer.